# I´m trying to print a misaligned pyramid

Tags: java

I´m having a little bit of trouble printing a pyramid with misaligned spacing, kinda like this:

```
         *
         **
        ***
        ****
       *****
       ******
```

I´m currently using this code which gives me a perfectly aligned pyramid, but my desired result is the spacing I specified above

```
    //Chueca
        for (int i = 1, j = 0; i <= numLineas; ++i,j=0){
     
       for(int espacio = 1; espacio <= numLineas-i; ++espacio){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        
        while(j != i){
            System.out.print("*");
            ++j;
        }            
        System.out.println();
    
    }`
```

IS there any way to modify this code to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried... well... anything?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition of the second `for` loop to only print half the spaces:

```java
for (int espacio = 1; espacio <= (numLineas - i) / 2; ++espacio) {
```

*Output*

```
  *
  **
 ***
 ****
*****
******
```